# Python Selenium - get element with a date-rolename

Tags: python, selenium, webautomation

I have the following HTML markup:

```
<div data-request-type="person" class="_entry _line _e _selected" id="c1055e27-0cfe-4f93-8bea-28a3421d842e" data-rolename="Member" data-isoptional="true">
    <div class="_subindicator _gray">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="_removePers">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="_voluntaryPers">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="_text">Member</div>
</div>
```

I have to click on the first `<div>` using `.click()`.

But now I don't know how to find this with selenium. I already tried it with XPATH, but I have several elements with different IDs on this page. And the IDs are always regenerated. This does not work.

Does anyone have an idea?

I tried it with a lot of solutions...but nothing works.

My last one - to take a inner div with class _text

```
   getAllMembers = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('td._text').get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Please help - how can I do this with Selenium? :-)

Comment: Did you get any errors on the click() ?  Can you provide the url and which element you are trying to click()?

Comment: @Sureshmani I geht an error that the Element can´t be found. The click() is not executed. I can´t provide the URL - because it is an intern website.

Comment: Did you try adding some wait before the click()? explicit wait would be ideal. did you check for iframes before this element?

Comment: I would be useful to know the url in order to text possible answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below xpath :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='_entry _line _e _selected'][@data-rolename='Member']"))).click()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: Maybe you can answer this question too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61437043/python-selenium-save-data-id-and-data-name-in-file

Answer (score 0):

To select and click on a element by its attribute, you can use:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://site.tld")
xpath = "//div[@data-rolename='Member']"
el = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
el.click()
```