# Python Selenium save data-id and data-name in file

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I have this HTML Code

```
<div id="availables" style="height: 472px; overflow-y: scroll;">
  <div class="_instance _personInstance _volunteer" data-id="980200" data-name="Name1">
    <div class="_addButtonPerson">&nbsp;</div>
      Name1
  </div>
  <div class="_instance _personInstance _volunteer" data-id="14069" data-name="Name2">
    <div class="_addButtonPerson">&nbsp;</div>
       Name2
  </div>
  <div class="_instance _personInstance _volunteer" data-id="514633" data-name="Name3">
    <div class="_addButtonPerson">&nbsp;</div>
      Name3
  </div>
```

Now I want to write the data-id and the data-name into a csv file.

> 980200, Name1
>
> 14069, name2
>
> 514633 Name3
>
> etc.

Only I can't get the data out. My code currently looks like this:

```
    findMember = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, '_instance _personInstance _volunteer')]")
      for element in findMember:
        with open('names.csv', 'w') as n:
          n.write(element.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-id]") + ',' + element.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-name]"))
```

There are no error messages - but the file is not created either.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Are you able to print the data fields that you want in the csv?

Comment: I tried it with: indMember = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, '_instance _personInstance _volunteer')]")
      for element in findMember:
 print(element.text)

but doesn´t work  - No errors - no output

Answer (score 0):

findMember = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, '_instance _personInstance _volunteer')]")
      for element in findMember:
        with open('names.csv', 'w') as n:
          n.write(element.get_attribute('data-id'), element.text)

Answer (score 0):

it takes a while, but now I found the solution for my Problem with help from Satheesh Answer:

```
findMember = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, '_instance _personInstance _volunteer')]")
with open('names.csv', 'w') as n:
    for element in findMember:
        n.write(element.get_attribute('data-id') + ', ' + element.get_attribute('data-name') + '\n')
```

Thanks :-)